# Convergent of sequence looking like Riemann zeta function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a question that: Given a non-negative sequence {$\epsilon_n$} ($n \in \mathbb{Z+}$) such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\epsilon_n = 0$.

Can we conclude that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z+}}\frac{\epsilon_n}{n} < +\infty$

Comment: no, only that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n n^{-s}$ converges for $Re(s) > 1$ (and $|\epsilon_n| < C$ is enough, no need that it $\to 0$). the converse is not true, for example $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s} = \eta(s-1)$ converges for $Re(s) > 1$ but $n (-1)^{n+1}$ is clearly not bounded

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what this has to do with zeta functions. The answer is no: take $\epsilon_n=1/\ln(n+1)$. Use the integral test to show the series diverges.